# Multiple streams on TcpClient on different ports?

Tags: c#, ssl, tcp, tcpclient

I am a bit confused with the `TcpClient` class. I want to connect to my server and have 2 streams. One SSL and one regular non secure TCP.

So i connect like this currently:

```
await _tcpClient.ConnectAsync(address,port);
IsConnected = true;
_networkStream = _tcpClient.GetStream();
_sslStream = new SslStream(_tcpClient.GetStream());
```

The problem is my ssl data i want to use on a different port. So do i need to have two TcpClient instances one for secure and one for non secure? Or can i have multiple streams on different ports with this class. I am confused how its done? I am really confused how this is meant to be setup properly.

Comment: If you are going to the same server you need to TcpClient objects with two different port numbers.  Is there any synchronization between the two clients?  Usually with SSL you have one port for commands and second port for transferring the data.  To reduce the amount of code, I would create a class for the Tcp code and create two instances of the class.

Comment: Yes i will create a class with both tcp clients in it i think. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you will need two separate `Socket` instances. You *could* to that via two instances of `TcpClient` - personally I tend to prefer raw sockets, but that's up to you.

Comment: Whats the difference between using `TcpClient` and `Socket` instances?

Comment: In theory `TcpClient` helps wrap a number of things to help you work with sockets more easily. But the API is such a thin abstraction that in most cases you can work just as easily against raw sockets, or at worst a `NetworkStream`.

Comment: Ah i see, i think i'll just use two TcpClients for now until i understand the syntax usage of sockets better. The whole begin/ call back setup vs TcpClient's async seems a bit confusing to me at the moment.

Comment: There is really no difference between TcpClient and Socket except the Tcp Constructor automatically sets some properties and hides some properties/methods.  The hidden properties/methods can be found in the TcpClient client property.